# Potential Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces, potential-energy

I really need help with this homework question. I thought the function very stranger to be a function of a potential energy. It´s seems to be like Lennard Jonnes pontential energy function. Am I right?

> A single conservative force $F ( x )$ acts on a particle of mass . The potential energy force is associated with 
>   $$U ( x ) = - ( x + 1 )e^{-2x}$$
>
> (a) Determine the force acting on the particle
>
> (b) What is the lowest energy value potential?
>
> (c) Outline graph of potential energy function of the position

Comment: This is a standard drill problem. Look up gradient of the potential.

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic problem: (a) $F=-\frac{d U(x)}{dx}$. (b) You need to find the minimum of $U(x)$; (c) Sketch a graph. For all the questions you can use wolframalpha. If I understood your problem correctly then [(a)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%28%20%28%20x%20%2B%201%20%29e%5E%28-2x%29%2Cx%29) and [(b,c)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum%20of%20-%20%28%20x%20%2B%201%20%29e%5E%28-2x%29) .

Comment: +1 the scientist of the future: just ask the right question to wolfram alpha